# Why my success call JSON data type response not behaving properly

Tags: jquery

I have an AJX call in my HTML page:

```
$.ajax({url:"forgetpwd.php",datatype:'json',type:'post',success:function(result){
                      alert(result);
                      alert(result.status);
                      if(result.status == "success")
                            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
                        alert('Done');
                    }});
            });
```

My forgetpwd.php PHP code is as below:

```
<?php
//mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
$response['status'] = 'success'; 
echo json_encode($response)
?>
```

My first alert in success AJAX function shows me values like:

```
{"status":"success"}
```

But the second one shows value as undefined while all other alerts messages are also getting displayed? Why result.status variable value is 'undefined'?

Comment: I think it should be `dataType` for intelligent guess, not `datatype`

Comment: typo in `datatype` should be camelCase  `dataType`.

Comment: @charlietfl Oh yes. Please put this as answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the issue. I have wrongly typed as datatype instead of dataType. It solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above the answer for this issue

```
**datatype** should be camelCase **dataType**
```

Like below code

```
$.ajax({url:"forgetpwd.php",dataType :'json',type:'post',success:function(result){
                  alert(result);
                  alert(result.status);
                  if(result.status == "success")
                        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
                    alert('Done');
                }});
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({url:"forgetpwd.php",dataType :'json',type:'post',success:function(result){
                      alert(result);
                      alert(result.status);
                      if(result.status == "success")
                            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
                        alert('Done');
                    }});
            });
```

Typo in the **dataType**  ==>  Refer this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/